# Auto-Drop down of combo box in DevExpress Xpf.Grid when clicking from one combo box to another

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, wpfdatagrid, devexpress-wpf

I am trying to enable 1-click editing of dropdown combo boxes inside a  `DevExpress.Xpf.Grid`, and am running into a rather unusual problem that I've not been able to find a solution to;

I want to be able to:

1. click on any cell that contains a combo box and have the 'Editor' immediately show the combo-box in the open state
2. then while the combo box is still open, click onto another cell, the current combo box should close, and the new one I just clicked should open (with combo-box open). 
   [image]

For example; If I clicked on cell A (To `Paris`), and then saw that it was the wrong cell, and immediately click Cell B(From `Vienna`) to it's left, what happens is that the second click appears to be captured as some type of 'close-combo' or `escape` event, and combo A (To `Paris`) closes, and the mouse `click` or `mouse-down` or `previewMouseXX` event is never captured anywhere else. i.e. while I've actually clicked on (From `Vienna`) that combo box never opens. ***If another combobox is already open then I actually have to double click to open cell B despite cell B being configured with   `immediatePopup="true"`.***

I've tried a bunch of approaches with no luck. (They all focus on getting the first cell I click to automatically open, and that works, but only for the first cell. )

Any assistance at all will be hugely appreciated.

txs,

Alan

here's some sample code that demonstrates the problem;

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Grid1"
        x:Class="Grid1.MainWindow"

        xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
        xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"  

        Title="Trip Details" Height="350" Width="625">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:TableView>
        <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name"/>

                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="From">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ImmediatePopup="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" AutoComplete="True" IsTextEditable="False" DisplayMember="Name" ValueMember="Id"/>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>

                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="To">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings  ImmediatePopup="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" AutoComplete="True" IsTextEditable="False" DisplayMember="Name" ValueMember="Id"/>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>

                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Depart"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Return"/>

            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

City class;

```
namespace Grid1
{
    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static List<City> GetCities()
        {
            return new List<City>()
            {
                new City() { Id = 1, Name = "London"},
                new City() { Id = 2, Name = "Paris"},
                new City() { Id = 3, Name = "Vienna"},
                new City() { Id = 4, Name = "Cambridge"}
            };
        }
    }

    public enum  CityId {  London = 1, Paris, Vienna, Cambridge }
}
```

and the viewmodel;

```
namespace Grid1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Customers = Trip.GetCustomers();
            Cities = City.GetCities();
        }

        public List<Trip> Customers { get; set; }
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Summary:

When a combobox has just opened as a result of a single-click (this works), when clicking away (immediately onto a second cell in order to get that cell to show it's combobox, that doesnt work), it's almost as if ***that*** click is turned into some type of `click-away` event, if such a thing even exists, and where you actually clicked is ignored and hit-testing at that spot is never done, and no further mouse event is raised. That new cell you clicked never even receives any focus or events. (as if the combo box swallowed the click)

Comment: So, genneraly you want to bind your ComobBox's IsDropDownOpen to your DataGridRow's IsSelected? or should they work independly?

Comment: It's not 'my' combobox, it's the combo from the gridEditor. Perhaps if you could please share sample code for binding along the lines you suggest then I could test to see if that approach would work?

Comment: @sTrenat I took a quick look and I couldn't see a way how to do that?

Comment: I don't know devexpress and don't have acces to it but i can make sample that works on build-in controls

Comment: I understand the general concept you're describing, unfortunately not sure that will help here? I've included the actual xaml, you can see there's no 'combobox' to bind to, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't know this control but I'm sure there is some property responsible for popup being visible, if not, you can always make attachedProperty assigned to some inner property which is set on when popup is Visible, like IsSelected/IsExpanded/IsOpened, and then, bind it to your row/cell IsSelected

Comment: Unfortunately that approach won't solve the main problem. I already can get the combo box to open with 1 click, that's not my main problem, the main problem (bolded at the top of my text) is once that combo box is open, clicking on another one merely acts like a "click-away" event (if such a thing exists) and the click into the new cell is never registered. If you really want to help, can you please run the sample I built for this question and suggest a fix that work with the sample? that will also help anyone else looking at this question in future. thanks in advance, Alan